# Using Pyradiomics to calculate shape features on meshes instead of matrices?

Tags: mesh, shapes, feature-extraction, imaging, stl-format

I am trying to compute some mesh features for 3D models that I created using numpy-stl. I would like to compute all of the features given within pyradiomics, but I am not sure how to use them on just the meshes without them having all of the extra binary image, and matrix information? Unless there is a better program t use for shape feature extraction? Also, in the documentation, it says that there are some features you need to enable C extensions for. How can you do that in your python script?

Answer (score 0):

C extensions are enabled by default. As of PyRadiomics 2.0, the python equivalents for those functions have been remove (horrible performance).

As to your meshes. PyRadiomics is build to extract features from images and binary labelmaps. To use meshes you would have to first convert them.

What features do you want to extract? PyRadiomics does use a sort of on-the-fly built mesh to calculate surface area and volume, which are also used in the calculation of several other shape features.
If you want to take a look at how volume and SA are calculated, the source code for that is in C (`radiomics/src/cshape.c`). The calculation of the derived features (e.g. sphericity) is in `shape.py`